# Kali live USB Boot -Stop Bleeping

Tags: boot, kali-linux, live-usb

I run Kali from a live boot USB. 
When I boot up a blue option screen appears along with a “ bleep”
How do I stop the “ bleep” - it’s driving my wife mad. Turning the volume down on the LT has no effect.
I guess it’s in grub, but I can’t find it.
Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of WIKLSH in my opinion. User has a legitimate question about system hardware...it just happens to come up when booting the like Kali image.

Comment: is `GRUB_INIT_TUNE` set in your GRUB configuration file?

Comment: Unable to find that particular grub file

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the internal speaker on your computer. You *might* be able to turn off the internal speaker in BIOS, but not necessarily.

Also, this isn't really a Kali-Linux issue; any bootloader or OS that uses the system-bell (may not be the right term, but its a command/control in the firmware) will make sounds through this speaker.